# Hide numbers of a phone number

Tags: php

How can I show and hide the some numbers of a phone number by replacing it with `*` like `0935***3256` by PHP?

EX:

> 09350943256 -> 0935***3256
>  09119822432 -> 0911***2432
>   09215421597 -> 0921***1597
> ...

---

```
$number = '09350943256';
echo str_pad(substr($number, -4), strlen($number), '*', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Top php code result is as: `*******3256` but i want result as: `0935***3256`

How is it?

Comment: this is a quite trivial task. use a clever combination of strlen, substr, str_repeat and the count of numbers you want on the right and left side

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use substr and concat  this way

to work for any $number with any number of n digit length

```
 <?php

     $number = "112222";
     $middle_string ="";
     $length = strlen($number);

     if( $length < 3 ){

       echo $length == 1 ? "*" : "*". substr($number,  - 1);

     }
     else{
        $part_size = floor( $length / 3 ) ; 
        $middle_part_size = $length - ( $part_size * 2 );
        for( $i=0; $i < $middle_part_size ; $i ++ ){
           $middle_string .= "*";
        }

        echo  substr($number, 0, $part_size ) . $middle_string  . substr($number,  - $part_size );
     }
```

The output if you make $number = "1" is *  and if $number = "12" is *2 and for $number = "112222" is 11**22. and it goes on.

Comment: @Mehdi   many thanks   .. answer  updated .. (wrong ,0, -4) need only -4

Answer (score 6):

In short:

```
$phone = 01133597084;
$maskedPhone = substr($phone, 0, 4) . "****" . substr($phone, 7, 4);
```

> // Output: 0113****7084

Comment: A nice simple solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substr_replace()` function

```
<?php
$mobnum ="09350943256";
for($i=4;$i<7;$i++)
{
  $mobnum = substr_replace($mobnum,"*",$i,1);
}
echo $mobnum;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substr()` to fetch the first 4 and last 4, and add four `*` in the middle manually, and put it all together in a string.

```
$phone = "09350943256";
$result = substr($phone, 0, 4);
$result .= "****";
$result .= substr($phone, 7, 4);
echo $result;
```

The above would output

> 0935****3256

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/oluf5)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php  
$phone='05325225990';

function stars($phone)
{
 $times=strlen(trim(substr($phone,4,5)));
 $star='';
 for ($i=0; $i <$times ; $i++) { 
  $star.='*';
 }
 return $star;
}

$result=str_replace(substr($phone, 4,5), stars($phone), $phone);
echo $result;

?>
```

0532*****90

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing the math of calculating indices, I suggest this „declarative“ solution:

```
<?php

$number='0123456789';
$matches=[];
preg_match('/(\\d{4})(\\d+)(\\d{4})/', $number, $matches);
$result=$matches[1].str_repeat('*',strlen($matches[2])).$matches[2];
print($result);

?>
```